# Tikz barchart space between bars within group

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

I have the following bar chart:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
              legend style={at={(1.2,1)},anchor=north},
              ybar,
              xticklabels={},
              bar width=0.6cm,
              width=5cm,
              height=5cm,
              grid=none,
              ymin=0,
              nodes near coords, style={xshift=0pt,yshift=0pt,anchor=north,font=\footnotesize},
              ]

            \addplot plot coordinates {(1, 3.0)};
            \addplot plot coordinates {(1, 0.7)};
            \addplot plot coordinates {(1, 0.9)};

            \legend{A, B, C}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

My question is: How can I increase the space between the bars?

Answer (score 2):

So if you do not need any more sophisticated solution, the following should work:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        pgfplotsset{
            ytick style={draw=none},
        }
    \begin{axis}[
          ybar=2pt, % change this of you have more than one bar per column
          x=0.9cm, % just play with the relation of these
          bar width=0.1cm, % just play with with the relation of these
          bar shift=0,
          height=5cm,
          width=5cm,
          grid=none,
          ymin=0,
          ymax=5,
          symbolic x coords={A,B,C},
          xmin=A,
          xmax=C,
          enlarge x limits=0.5,
          ytick pos=left,
          ytick={0,...,5},
          xtick pos=left,
          xtick={A,...,C},
          tick align=outside,
          nodes near coords,
          style={xshift=0pt,yshift=0pt,anchor=north,font=\footnotesize},
          ]

        \addplot coordinates {(A, 3.0)};
        \addplot coordinates {(B, 0.7)};
        \addplot coordinates {(C, 0.9)};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Just play with x and bar widths, that should do for your plot.
Still there are a lot of examples and forum entries already that would have given you an answer, so maybe next time try to google ;).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. How would I get a legend as in my example above. That was the reason why I put all three bars in the same column, but then I could not adjust the space between them. Sorry for my newbie questions, but I googled a lot and unfortunately could not find a satisfying answer.

Comment: You are welcome ;). For a legend just add "legend position = north east" and than \legend{A, B, C} as you did in your example. And in your example you made three columns. For one column write \addplot coordinates {(y1, x1), (y2, x2), (y3, x3)}. To change the space between then, adjust the ybar value. Regards